# Google cloud sql proxy can't find service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to connect to google cloud SQL using `cloud_sql_proxy`, I've followed the steps that [google provided](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview?authuser=1#expandable-1). I have a service account in the directory I'm running my commands on and I ran this command first:

```
  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=‘service-account.json’
```

Then I ran the command needed to connect:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=instance-name:europe-west1:project:project=tcp:5432
```

But when I run this it gives me this error:

```
2022/10/22 12:54:36 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {Current = 8500, Max = 1048576}
2022/10/22 12:54:37 invalid json file "‘service-account.json’": open ‘service-account.json’: no such file or directory
```

I've tried to change the `export` command to say `./service-account`, `~/absolute/path/to/service-account.json` and all resulted in the same error.

I'm running the command where both `service-account.json` and `cloud_sql_proxy` are located and when I run `ls -la` it really does show them.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotation and you will be fine.